# Grunt: Updating value in YAML file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yaml

I am working on my buildscript and I need to update a value inside a YAML (`.yml` to be precise) file.

For easier development, I simply defined it as my default task:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', function() {
    var conf = grunt.file.readYAML('config.yml');

    // Shows correct contents of config.yml
    console.log(conf);

    // Changing the value of key 'deploy'
    conf['deploy'] = 'Hello World';

    // Trying to write the updated data back to file
    grunt.file.write('config.yml', conf);

    // Re-reading the new file
    var conf2 = grunt.file.readYAML('config.yml');

    // logs [ 'object Object' ]
    console.log(conf2);
});
```

I think my comments make pretty clear what I am trying to do – updating a configuration setting.

The reason `[ 'object Object' ]` is being logged is because that is actually written to that file. That means I can't simply do `grunt.file.write('config.yml', conf);`, I need something like `JSON.stringify` but for YAML. Does something like this exist? How to update a value inside a yml file in Grunt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example with this:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/yamljs

You can do that:

```
YAML = require('yamljs');
grunt.file.write('config.yml', YAML.stringify(conf));
```

Comment: Wow, that was easier that I thought. Thank you!